# How to ignore PHP error when cart is Empty

Tags: php, conditional-statements

How do I catch the error when my shopping cart is empty?

```
<?php
   if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
       echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
       $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
       for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
           $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
           $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
           $pname=get_product_prod_name($pid);
           if($q==0) continue;
           ?>
           <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
               <td>₱<?php echo get_prod_price($pid)?></td>
               <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="2" size="2" /></td>                    
               <td>₱<?php echo get_prod_price($pid)*$q?></td>
               <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td></tr>
           <?php                    
       }
       ?>
       <tr><td><b>Order Total: ₱<?php echo get_order_total()?></b></td><td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="button" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"><input type="button" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()"><input type="button" value="Check Out" onclick="window.location='billing.php?'"></td></tr> <!--Previously billing.php?command=update -->
       <?php
    }

    else{
        echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
    }
?>
```

There is an else statement when I don't have anything in the cart, but it still says that I have an identified index. How do I remove that error?

And a follow up question is how do I make the checkout button unclickable when the user is not logged in?

Comment: Your cart's done wrong anyways. the key should be the productID, so you don't have to scan the entire cart every time the user wants to update a quantity. `$_SESSION['cart'][$productID] = array('quantity'] => 50);` makes life a LOT easier, and then you can use a simple foreach() loop as well, without knowing how many/few items are in the array.

Comment: Im new to this. haha. How do i do it? @MarcB

Comment: you can just check if is set first with isset($yourSomething), it will return TRUE or FALSE depending on if it is set.

Comment: To disable the button, make another if else to check for `$_SESSION ['user_id']` and put clickable/disabled buttons in them.. I'd normally check for session an if not exists, ask for email address and give 2 options below... To enter password in case of returning users and another to either proceed without password or provide a password to create account then call auth function after add function was successful and then redirect to shipping address page or wherever required..

Comment: Can u also share a phpfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you rearrange your cart array so that productID becomes the key, then

change quantity:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$productID] = $quantity;
```

remove from cart:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]);
```

And iterating the cart becomes:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $productID => $quantity) {
  ... do something ...
}
```

As long as you properly do a `$_SESSION['cart'] = array()` when the cart's first started, the foreach loop simply won't do anything in the cart's empty.

Comment: Hmm. I dont know how to start, I just followed the code from [link] (http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=25&title=Tutorial-Building-a-shopping-cart-in-PHP) I have no idea what i am doing. i appreciate your help but i am really new with this. i am having a hard time fixing it.